# Inkscape: Segments disappear from pdf export

Tags: inkscape, pdf, export

I made this very simple SVG in Inkscape 1.2.2:
https://svgshare.com/s/rbx

The pdf export (default export settings) looks like this:

[image]

All of the horizontal segments are missing (everything else is there). The LaTeX typesetting is done with [TeXText](https://textext.github.io/textext/) (although that shows up fine).

I've tried ungrouping, applying transforms, deep ungroup etc. (as inspired by other posts), and nothing seems to work. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Illustrator with the SVG... it won't export properly either. The "A drawing error has occurred" is presented for the PDF.

Here's why....

- The strokes all use a **gradient**. They should be set to a **solid color**.
- The `=` signs are *also* filled with gradients. Not sure why.

Just a good idea..

- The stroke weights are thin - all set to 0.164pts. As a minimum one really should use **0.25pts** for stroke weights. 0.25pts is the desired minimum for printing.

So... Setting stroke weights to a minimum of 0.25pts and a *solid black*. And setting the `=` signs to a solid blue, *then* results in a viable PDF from Illustrator.

PDF screenshot ...
[image]

Note the PDF from AI was failing specifically due to the gradients - both on the strokes and the `=` signs.

I don't know if these same issues are what's causing Inkscape to choke on the SVG, but I'd wager it's a good guess.

Comment: I think it is the same issue.  Inkscape calls these "swatch fills".  Inkscape displays it just fine, it's the export to PDF which seems to cause issues. This was probably caused by the work not being entirely created natively within Inkscape. The OP used TeXText for some of the elements.

Comment: Yup. The strokes display fine in AI.. they just don't export to PDF correctly. And the two `=` had the same issue with their fills.

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with the stroke colour of the horizontal lines which have been set to "Swatch" colours.  Changing to a normal solid stroke colour fixes some of them, but not all, so something else is up somewhere, but I can't quite pinpoint all the issues. The problem likely has something to do with TeXText, rather than Inkscape per se. Inkscape can have problems with elements created in other software.

What I would do is just remove all these horizontal lines and replace them with new lines with a stroke set to a normal black stroke colour.

This seems to resolve the issue. I tested it. Here's the screen shot in Adobe Reader.

[image]

Comment: `something else is up somewhere, but I can't quite pinpoint all the issues` check the gradient fills on the `=` signs.. that was the same issue as the strokes in AI.

Comment: Indeed, it also works on my end now, and changing from the swatch to the solid colors fixed it.